# error displaying on wordpress website loading

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, server

I have wordpress website and last week that server was hacked by some hacker group.

While the hosting provider said that all websites are recovered and working fine,  there was an error coming from my website.

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in H:\root\home\cmadurawala-001\www\site1\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 492"
```

I need to resolve this. If anyone can help me

Comment: Did you tried to change your php version? Also try to activate debug constant into config.php wordpress file to see more details about your error, and,also, check out your error.log and paste what else you're retriveing

Comment: Can you guide me to how to do this, actually im not familiar with wordpress n php

Comment: About activate debug mode in wordpress see this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228525/debugging-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If your Site is working Properly then you can turn off that PHP errors.

Inside your `wp-config.php` file, look for the following line:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

It is also possible, that this line is already set to false. In that case, you’ll see the following code:

```
 define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

In either case, you need to replace this line with the following code:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```